# Rails Javascript - jQuery converted to Javascript with Rails 7 is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rails 7 with Turbo / Hotwire.  I am reusing code that I copied from an old ~ 2018 project.  This code / jQuery was working for an informational popup:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#info').hover(function() {
        $('#popup').show();
        }, function() {
        $('#popup').hide();
        });
      });
```

After rewriting it javascript ( correctly? ), this is what I'm currently testing - unsuccessfully:

```
      $(document).addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      $('#info_1').onmouseover(function() {
        $('#popup_1').show();
        }, function() {
        $('#popup_1').hide();
        });
      });
```

I have `#info_1` / `id=info_1` in one `div` and the popup `#popup_1` / `id=popup_1` in another `div` directly below the first one.

I've tested placing the javascript in the `app/javascript/custom/menu.js` file as well as using it in `<script></script>` tags on the view page.

How should I be handing this.

Thanks

Comment: Reading the errors in the console can be very useful in debugging. For instance you would have seen `$(...).addEventListener is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the $() means you are still using jquery, you've not converted it to plain javascript, but you have converted it to broken jquery. every line that uses $().someChained function needs replacing. eg:

$(document).addEventListener

should be

document.addEventListener

heres a gist of what you want, with one note to watch out for DOMContentLoaded, if it's loaded before the listener is bound it'll never fire.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

  info.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    popup.style.display = 'block';
  });

  info.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    popup.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

side note, if replacing a non trivial projects jquery with plain js is falling to you and you are unfamiliar with the language at all this will be a very very hard task.

Comment: You can also assign the event directly e.g. `info.onmouseover = function(){}`

Comment: @danielRicado - Thanks, it's working.  And you correctly interpret my JS skills.  I learned to code as a hobby about 10 years ago, went through a lot of online tutorials, Flatiron's prep course (was accepted but didn't pursue it), and the Thinkful Rails course.  Never did understand JS - and got really confused when it went to arrows.  Primarily do projects in Rails.  Thanks again, Doug